# Subversion: error on checkout - Mac OS 10.5

Tags: svn, macos

I'm running Mac OS 10.5

I'm trying to do a checkout of a online repository to a local folder, using the svn checkout command:

```
svn checkout [url] --username [username] --password [password] [targetfolder]
```

It starts adding files to my new working directory as expected, but then throws the following error:

```
svn: In directory 'svn/trunk/webservices/admin/system/application/controllers'
svn: Can't copy 'svn/trunk/webservices/admin/system/application/controllers/.svn/tmp/text-base/contentPanel.php.svn-base' to 'svn/trunk/webservices/admin/system/application/controllers/.svn/tmp/contentPanel.php.tmp.tmp': No such file or directory
```

I've tried to use:

- SCPlugin,
- svnX,
- fink's subversion client, (1.4.4)
- collabnet's subversion package (subversion 1.6.2, includes 1.4.6 svn-client).

...and all result in the same error when trying to create the working directory.

An `svn export` of the same repo works fine.  So something in the .svn folders for that directory is amiss?

The repo-admin says he managed to do a checkout to a clean local folder on his ubuntu machine without issue.

What else can I try to get this local working directory up?  I need to work on this source too!

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A shot in the dark -- is it possible that that there's another file in the same directory that varies only in case? For example `ContentPanel.php` or `contentpanel.php`? As I recall, on OS X (depending on how your file system is set up), this can cause some issues when you try to check files out...

The target file being `.tmp.tmp` seems to indicate this...

Here's a [link](http://tortoisesvn.net/node/167) I just found...

We had this issue on our repository recently and it was very puzzling for a while.

Is the online repository public? If so, can you provide it so we can take a look...?

Comment: This could be checked fairly easily looking at the repository.

Comment: There are 2 contentpanel.php files, you're right!  I've asked the repo-admin to sort them out, assuming one is a duplicate.  Will do a fresh checkout soon and let you know - thanks!

Comment: Yep, removing the duplicate file names fixed this problem.  Thanks for the help Andrew.

Answer (score 1):

Check your disk quota / free space.  I experienced the same symptoms on another BSD system when close to my quota for the disk — I had enough free space to export, but checking out gave me the somewhat enigmatic "No such file or directory" error.